# Mongo beginner, query inner array

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to generate a mongo query that will return all entries where mktid=x and selctionid=y as per below. SelectionId is a member of an actors  array as per below.

I have tried multiple things like this

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({mktid:"334455555",'actors.selectionId' : "443311555"})
```

and

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({mktid:"334455555",'actors.0.selectionId' : "443311555"})
```

The DB:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "55098030e4b02da345b0a2ed"
  },
  "mktid": "55555555",
  "dubious": false,
  "state": "OPEN"
  "actors": [
    {
      "selectionId": 3333333,
      "activityid": 0,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
    },
    {
      "selectionId": 4444445gg,
      "activityid": 0,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
    },
    {
      "selectionId": xccfffff,
      "activityid": 0,
      "status": "ACTIVE",
    }
   ]
}
```

{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "55098030e44b02da345b0a2ed"
      },
      "mktid": "5555552",
      ----
      ---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.getCollection('mycollection').find({mktid:"334455555", actors: {
                $elemMatch: {
                     selectionId: "443311555"
                }
      }
});
```

See the "Query an Array of Documents" section here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Comment: Hi @Mark, thanks for your answer, you answered my question exactly as I asked it and I have accepted it as correct.. However I didn't know what I really wanted until i saw the result!! I have asked another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29261073/mongo-query-limit-results-on-member-of-inner-array instead of modifying this question to be something else.